# What does the url in XML file mean

Tags: html, xml, url

I find this URL (or a similar one) always on HTML files, XML, XSD...
Like "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" or "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
I always wonder what those URLs means.
Even offline the XML or HTML document works without changes. What's the benefits on links to those URLs??
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those URLs do not necessarily point to any website/server. They are a convenient naming mechanism. The idea is since every company will have a unique website, using that as their namespace will avoid clashes. Hence better interoperability. Hence the custom.

[Namespaces in XML 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)

Answer (score -1):

It's the [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema).

> An XML schema provides a view of the
>   document type at a relatively high
>   level of abstraction.